# PHP - Get list of databases names

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I get a list of all the MySQL databases that exist on a server using PHP?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_conn,"SHOW DATABASES"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo $row[0]."<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: ^^ thumbs up. for mysqli.. `$result = mysqli_query($db_conn,"SHOW DATABASES"); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row[0]."<br>"; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
$dbcnx = mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword); 
$result = @mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES'); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
 print_r ($row)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) prompt, `SHOW DATABASES` does what you want.

You can run this command as a query from PDO or the native PHP MySQL library and read the returned rows. Pretend it is a normal select.

You will only see the databases that the account used to connected to MySQL can see.

Answer (score -2):

The MySQL command for this is

```
SHOW DATABASES
```

See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show.html) for more info on the SHOW command

Answer (score -2):

Write the [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) query:

```
  show databases
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use `SHOW DATABASES`.It will show all the databases present in your MySQL.